# Python check if Left Mouse Button is being held?

Tags: python, winapi, mouseclick-event, pynput, onmouseclick

I'm pretty new to Python and I'd like to make a kind of an Autoclicker, which keeps clicking every 0.1 seconds when my left mouse button is held down.
My Problem is, that when I run my script, my mouse instantly starts clicking. What should I do?:

```
import win32api
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()

while True:

    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01):
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Problem is, that when I run my script, my mouse instantly starts clicking. What should I do?**

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

You should use `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01)&0x8000` instead.

**Now, the only thing it does is click once, which makes my click a double click.**

Because `GetAsyncKeyState` detects the key state of the left mouse button. When you press the left mouse button, the `click` function is called, `click` will realize the two actions of the left mouse button press and release. Then in the place of the `while` loop, `GetAsyncKeyState` will detect the release action, which is why it stops after double-clicking.

I suggest you set the left mouse button to start and the right mouse button to stop.

Code Sample:

```
import win32api
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()

while True:

    if (win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01)&0x8000 > 0):
        flag = True
        while flag == True:
               mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
               time.sleep(0.1)
               if (win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x02)&0x8000 > 0):
                   flag = False
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Yeah that thing wouldn't be a problem, but I want it to actually work while i hold down my left mouse button. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: @user13591244 The left mouse button has two states: pressed and released. Because the mouse is continuously clicking, using `GetAsyncKeyState` cannot accurately capture the correct release state which you want to stop clicking. I suggest you use the left and right buttons to control separately.

Comment: Alright, so it's not possible. I'll try to make it that I have to hold down mouse5. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) < 0` in the if condition.

Comment: Now, the only thing it does is click once, which makes my click a double click. What should I do to make it keep clicking when I hold down my mouse button? It's even the same when I turn the 'if' into a 'while.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with mouse5!

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()

def ac():
    if keystate < 0:
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        pass

while True:
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x06)
    ac()
```